# Is there any possibility to convert string timestamp to float or datetime using java

Tags: java, python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I was writing a java code which generate random numbers from 1 to 1000 with timestamp. I have represented timestamp with the following source code

```java
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:sss");
Date date = new Date();
String a=dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(a);
```

I was able to store the data as .txt file which contains 1000 random numbers and its corresponding timestamp
When I was try to load the particular .txt file in python using pandas dataframe.
The file was loaded successfully and it was displaying with dataframe and it looks like this,

```
    HR   Age    RR  SPo2    Temperature     Timestamp
0   89   70     15  100     36  2020/09/22 12:46:009
1   130  27     15  96      37  2020/09/22 12:46:009
2   93   47     13  100     36  2020/09/22 12:46:009
3   116  53     15  98      36  2020/09/22 12:46:009
4   100  63     14  98      36  2020/09/22 12:46:009
```

Afterwards, I tried to fit a Random Forest after train/test split:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2) 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

classifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, criterion='gini', random_state=1, max_depth=3)
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-8f779aefd162> in <module>
     20 #Create a Gaussian Classifier
     21 classifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, criterion='gini', random_state=1, max_depth=3)
---> 22 classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)
     23 
     24 #y_pred=classifier.predict(X_test)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    293         """
    294         # Validate or convert input data
--> 295         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
    296         y = check_array(y, accept_sparse='csc', ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    297         if sample_weight is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    529                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    530                 else:
--> 531                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    532             except ComplexWarning:
    533                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2020/09/22 12:46:009'
```

I was so confused with this. Could anyone help me to get out of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have to encode your categorical data (dates) into numerical data, since the classifier can not work with your dates, but requires numbers.

You can use the [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) from sklearn to process all your dates before passing your data into your classifier.

But as mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311494/best-practice-for-encoding-datetime-in-machine-learning), it would be useful to keep the cyclic nature of dates:

> You want to preserve the cyclical nature of your inputs. One approach
> is to cut the datetime variable into four variables: year, month, day,
> and hour. Then, decompose each of these (except for year) variables in
> two.
>
> You create a sine and a cosine facet of each of these three variables
> (i.e., month, day, hour), which will retain the fact that hour 24 is
> closer to hour 0 than to hour 21, and that month 12 is closer to month
> 1 than to month 10.

So essentially you need to think about how you want to put your datetime into numbers, so that the classifier can work with it.